# Correctly handling the BFCache in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, next.js, bfcache

I'm showing a loading screen (state) before redirecting to an external url (payment provider), since they tend to load for a while.

If the user chooses not to complete the payment and goes `history.back()` (Gesture, back button, ...) the browser pulls the page before from the [BFCache](https://web.dev/bfcache/), including the loading state, and the user will be "stuck" loading forever.

How would you suggest handling that?   Persisted loads can be detected using the `pageshow` event, but I'm not sure if that is the react way to handle the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persisted loads should be handled manually. In your case you should handle the
loader state based on the event property `persisted` from `pageshow` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I ended up using `pageshow` event

```js
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
useEffect(() => {
    window.onpageshow = function(event) {
      if (event.persisted) {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
  }, []);
```